# How to get increament value in jquery when page is load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have

```
$ i=1 , $i =2, $i=3;
```

when page is loaded i need to pass all **$i** value to jquery

```
<?php   
    $i=1; 
    foreach($details as $value)
    {
      i++;
?>
      <input type ="hidden" id="social"  value="<?php echo $i?>"> 
<?php
    }
?>
```

I have tried i am getting only **$i=1 as output** . i need to get all $i value when page is load

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){             
             var social=$('#social').val();   
             alert(social);                  

    });
</script>
```

Comment: your foreach loop create multiple  input field with same id.This is not valid

Comment: what is the point of looping through $details if you don't use its values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `class` instead of `id` in `input`

```
<?php   $i=1; 
    foreach($details as $value){?>
<input type ="hidden" class="social"  value="<?php echo $i?>"> 
<?php $i++; }?>
}?>
```

Then traverse all `.social`

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){             
             $('.social').each(function()
             {   
             console.log($(this).val());                  
             } 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs have to be unique, you can't have multiple inputs with the same ID. Use a class instead, and then create an array of all the values.

```
<?php   $i=1; 
    foreach($details as $value){?>
<input type ="hidden" class="social"  value="<?php echo $i?>"> 
<?php $i++; }?>
}?>
```

Then in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var social = $(".social").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    alert(JSON.stringify(social));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All your input id is same, so jQuery only taking the value of first element. Change the code to

```
  <?php   $i=1; 
  foreach($details as $value){?>
  <input type ="hidden" id="social<?php echo $i-1; ?>"  value="<?php echo $i?>"> 
  <?php $i++; }?>
```

And in jQuery use

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){ 
             var phpVar = <?php echo $i; ?>;
             for( ; phpVar > 0; phpVar--)
             {
                var social=$('#social'+phpVar).val();   
                alert(social);    
             }


    });
</script>
```

Check the live example link: [Click here](http://area51.thedct.net/delete.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check This
For a dynamic element, get the value must be using class or dynamic id .
Not us static id 
**php code**

```
    <ul style="list-style:none"> 
    <?php   $i=1; 
        $cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
       foreach($cars as $car){ ?>

        <li class="list" value="<?php echo $i ?>"> <a href="#"><?php echo $i ?> </a> </li>

        <?php $i++; }?>
      </ul>
```

**Script**

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".list").on('click',function(){
         var listitem= $(this).val();
         alert(listitem)
      });



    });
</script>
```